# AngularJS CORS api with Jersey

Tags: angularjs, cors, jersey-2.0

I'm having problems on calling a CORS enabled service through AngularJS.
This is my scenario:

I have a CORS enabled Jersey 2.3 server on http://localhost:4567

```
@Provider
public class CORSFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {
    @Override
    public void filter(final ContainerRequestContext requestContext,
                       final ContainerResponseContext cres) throws IOException {
        cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8000");
        cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
        cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
    }
}
```

I have a nodejs server on http://localhost:8000 serving static content (angularjs libraries, my javascript etc)

Here is my angular service for calling my jersey API:

```
app.service("myapi", ["$http", function($http) {
    this.backend = "http://localhost:4567"

    this._header = function(token) {
        return {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": "Bearer "+token,
        }
    }

    this.mysharings = function(token, hash) {
        var serverurl = this.endpoints['path'] + '/' + hash;
        return $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: serverurl,
            headers: this._header(token),
        });
    };
    this.cards = function(token) {
        return $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: this.endpoints["path2"],
            headers: this._header(token)
        });
    };
}]);
```

Funny thing is that: cards() method works great (browser sends an OPTION request and then the actual GET), while mysharings() method fails.

In particular, I don't detect any HTTP request (no OPTION neither GET), but only this json:

```
{"data":null,"status":-1,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"http://localhost:4567/path2","headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Authorization":"Bearer 4gr7gb6jspnr4buchmhir9rc3u"},"withCredentials":false},"statusText":""}
```

And no information on log console.

I actually can change both code from server and client.

Do you have any idea? I have found many articles here and on the web, but no method was useful.

Thanks in advance

S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not CORS related.

My browser (both Firefox and Chrome) have uBlock Origin and Disconnect extensions installed.

Disabling them made the GET request working